# Flask PyMongo string back to ObjectID

Tags: mongodb, flask, pymongo, pymongo-3.x, flask-pymongo

I am using flask with pymongo and I have a case where my Object Id is being converted into a string. How can I change it back to an Object Id so I can use if for querying ?

```
From : 59d7ef576cab3d6118805a20
type is <class 'str'>

To: ObjectId("59d7ef576cab3d6118805a20")
type is <class 'bson.objectid.ObjectId'>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `bson.objectid.ObjectId` to create an ObjectId from a string. See the docs for this on the pymongo site: http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html

For example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

client = MongoClient()
collection = client.test.test

print(collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId("59d7ef576cab3d6118805a20")}))
```

The `bson` package is installed with pymongo. You don't need to install a separate bson package.